# xsl:param namespace error (may not be used in namespace)

Tags: xml, xslt, variables, namespaces, stylesheet

I don't understand why the xsl:param is giving me an error of 'Keyword xsl:param may not be used in namespace http://www.w3.org/TR/WD-xsl.' in the following xsl code with the style sheet declaration.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="uri:xsl">
```

Given the xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<catalog>
    <cd n="a">
        <title>Empire Burlesque</title>
        <artist>Bob Dylan</artist>
        <country>USA</country>
        <company>Columbia</company>
        <price>10.90</price>
        <year>1985</year>
    </cd>
</catalog>
```

and the xsl code

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="uri:xsl">

<xsl:param name="test" select="'a'"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
  <body>
    <h2>My CD Collection</h2>
    <table border="1">
      <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Artist</th>
      </tr>
      <xsl:for-each select="catalog/cd">

<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when match=".[@n = $test]">
      <tr>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="title" /></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="artist" /></td>
      </tr>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>

    </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>

      </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I can't change the Style Sheet Declaration. Looking over the w3c documentation I'm allowed to declare param as a child of stylesheet and it doesn't need to be in a template.

Comment: Looking over the w3c documentation you're not using XSL in the first place (the namespace attached to the `xsl` prefix matters).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your stuff is not in the namespace http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform then it is not an XSLT stylesheet and I have no idea what else it is. No XSLT processor will do anything useful with it. There might be a some kind of language with the namespace "uri.xsl" but if there is, I've never come across it and I nave no idea what it might be.

Answer (score 1):

I see three errors in your xslt:

1) You have two processing instructions at the beginning of the transform. You should use one, only, if any.

2) The namespace for stylesheet element should be `http://www.w3.org./1999/XSL/Transform`

3) You are missing the stylesheet version attribute

Apart these points, your stylesheet should work.

Comment: I updated the code above. You are right about (1) but I need to have the declaration <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="uri:xsl"> since I need to use <xsl:when match=".[@n = $test]"> as oppose to <xsl:when test....

Comment: @Steven, your comment about `uri:xsl` makes no sense really - you need to supply more info.

Comment: I'm working with a legacy code that has that declaration. When I substitute uri:xsl with http://www.w3.org./1999/XSL/Transform the element <xsl:when match=".[@n = $test]"> no-longer functions since it will be expecting a test instead of a match.

Comment: That `<xsl:when match="X">` looks as if it is from the Microsoft WD-xsl language which was around for a short time in Internet Explorer 4 days (1998, before XSLT 1.0 came out). However, the usual namespace URI for that language is "http://www.w3.org/TR/WD-xsl" (it's based on an early draft of XSLT 1.0, with many Microsoft variations). It's years since I've heard of anyone using this language.

Comment: Just to add: It's very hard to find a specification for the WD-xsl language nowadays; you'll probably need to browse a second-hand book shop to find one. (I think I threw mine out - sorry!) You certainly can't assume that XSLT elements like xsl:param are available for use.